# How to find the summation of the following series?

Tags: summation, power-series

I want to find
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{n^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 r^{n^2}
$$
r<1

Comment: The first can be expressed in terms of infinite products https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product . Apply the operator $ x \frac{d}{dx} $ to obtain the second.

Comment: Notice that the second series is nothing but

$$n^2 r^{n^2} = r \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r} (r^{n^2})$$

Anyway, those series are infinite since the upper limit is infinite... It would be more interesting to have $M$ instead of $\infty$

Comment: @HenryTuring: both series converge for $|r|<1$ !?

Comment: They are basically theta functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ah sorry! I did not read the $r < 1$ footnote!

Comment: @HenryTuring: neither did I.